# What is this strange whitespace in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2, whitespace

In Sublime Text 2, some of my whitespace behaves strangely.

For example, I select the contents of a script (as shown in the screenshot below), and do <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (to reduce indentation) it only works on the lines with *normal* spacing, resulting in my code indentation becoming all wonky.

**Notes:**

- the *non-space* white spaces are *not* tabs,
- it's set to indent using spaces
- doing "*convert tabs to spaces*" has no effect.
- My settings file has: `"draw_white_space": "all",`

I think this only happens with code pasted from elsewhere (like [OneNote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_OneNote)), and the only way I've found to deal with it is to manually replace the spacing with actual spaces.

What is the explanation for this behavior? Or is there a way to better deal with it?

[image: Weird whitespace]

Comment: And you believe it's not some sort of UTF-8-ish characters that aren't counted (by default) as whitespace?

Comment: Not really sure I guesse. I save as UTF-8, and they still display as pictured above.

Comment: That would preserve any non-ASCII-ish stuff: look at it with a hex dump and see what's actually there.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to do a hex dump, but I think I did soemthign vaguely equivalent (pasted as HTML to browser with a plugin). It looks like the renegade spaces are actually `&#160;`'s (or non-breaking spaces)

Comment: not sure why I didn't think of it before, but I just did a find replace (selected a nbsp and did ctrl+h) with a regular space. IDK if there's a better way to go about it, but that seems reasonably easy.

Comment: Don't know what else you'd do, although I suspect you could customize what's considered whitespace. IMO it's better to replace it anyway. Also, that's a danger of pasting anything from non-text sources.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Dave. If you want a checkmark and some nerd-points, feel free to write up an answer.

Comment: Without posting the source code it is difficult to diagnose exactly. Some candidates are U+00A0 ([NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=156&number=128)), U+2009 ([THIN SPACE](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9)), U+200B ([ZERO WIDTH SPACE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)), U+200C ([ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8704&number=128)), and U+FEFF ([ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=65272&number=128))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd assume they're something non-ASCII-ish that *looks* like whitespace, but actually isn't.

When I have files like this I generally hex dump them from the command line, or you can install a Sublime hex editor like [HexViewer](https://github.com/facelessuser/HexViewer) via normal package management that lets you do some fun stuff.

Once you know what the offending character(s) are you can use regular search-and-replace to make them be actual spaces, tabs, or whatever seems appropriate.

Comment: [*from comments above*]  It looks like the renegade spaces are actually `&#160;`'s (non-breaking spaces). A find-replace cleared it right up. Thanks Dave!

Comment: @ZachLysobey, I am curious how do you replace non-breaking space with normal space in sublime text.

Comment: @jdhao I just cut-and-pasted the non-breaking space into the *find* field, and typed a normal space into the *replace*. You can probably also do this with regex find-replace using unicode code-point matching (https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: I am able to find the `no-break space` using `\x{a0}` and replace it with normal space, thanks.